# Store binary strings mysql

Tags: mysql, binary

I am trying to figure out what the best way is to save binary data displayed as a string of 0s and 1s in mysql. The data has varies lengths and must be suitable to store up to 60000 bytes.

As varbinary can also store strings of characters i am confused how the data is stored and if i might need a translation beforehand to improve the space of the database. The same counts for a blob. So what is the most efficient way to safe binary data in the form of zeros and ones?

Comment: *varbinary can also store strings of characters* No. Varbinary stores an array of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Store data as Integer type may be better. And do transform task (decimal to binary and binary to decimal) in backend layer.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience **BLOB** will do the job for you. You can do better also if you embrace the string with **COMPRESS('')** mysql function before (obviusly this must be decompressed with DECOMPRESS() when you read).